# Why nx serve doesn't work when installed globally with Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, nomachine-nx

I initiated an Nx workspace using `npx`:

```sh
npx create-nx-workspace
```

I get this after nx finished bootstrapping my workspace:

```sh
 This means that you might have to use "yarn nx" or "npx nx" to execute command
s in the workspace.
  Run "yarn global add nx" or "npm install -g nx" to be able to execute command
directly.
```

I want execute command directly and want to use yarn so:

```sh
yarn global add nx
```

and get success message:

```sh
yarn global v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "nx@12.5.8" with binaries:
      - nx
Done in 9.40s.
```

I cd into my workspace, and try to serve my 'todos' app using the nx cli that I installed previously:

```sh
cd myorg
nx serve todos
```

but I get this error:

```sh
bash: nx: command not found
```

I restarted my terminal and tried to `serve` again but got the same error. `serve` works if I do `yarn nx serve todos`, but, I would love to learn why and how I can make the direct command work with Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

**Have the same problem?**

**You Should try out this one**

command line:-

npx nx serve [your application name]